# How to create a screenshot of the Linux command line shown on the monitor - No X running

Tags: linux, console, screenshot

I need to see the monitor of the linux system I am connected to by SSH. I know I can dump the contents of the console as ASCII characters, but this won't show me how the characters are rendered exactly. I'd like to receive a PNG or the like so I can see the real contents of the monitor.

The kernel does not use a framebuffer console but the standard one.

**IMPORTANT:** Because my other question was closed by someone: There is no X running on the console! I want to do a snapshot of the console you get e.g. by pressing Alt-F1 or by sending chvt 1 to the kernel. This is usually a plain text console, and I want to screenshot THAT, not some X session running somewhere.

I know I cannot display that screenshot in SSH, of course. That's why I want a PNG or some other raw format containing the pixels of that console.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned there's no framebuffer, just BIOS text mode.

In BIOS 80x25 text mode, there are no pixels – the kernel just directly puts text and attributes in the VGA memory, and the display adapter renders it somehow. (Hence "text mode".) The only way to make a screenshot of text-mode tty would be to physically capture from the VGA/HDMI/DP output, but it is out of reach for the OS.

(The OS can load a custom font into the VGA memory, e.g. Linux allows arbitrary .psf format fonts to be used, but you can't really know which font is currently loaded.)

If the text console *had* been running in framebuffer mode (using Linux's FBCON), you could screenshot that through /dev/fb0 using `fbgrab`.

Additionally, if the remote system was a server with a BMC (baseboard management controller, such as DRAC or iLO) built in, then that BMC would typically offer a "remote console" or "vKVM" feature which is able to show the screen's contents regardless of mode, by having the BMC directly access the display adapter's memory after it had already rendered the text. Some "business" desktops may also have this available through Intel AMT, although it needs to be pre-configured.

Comment: This is a great explanation but Is it not *also* true that there is nothing rendered on the host to "grab" persay?  SSHing in is subject to the terminal program being used by the client.  This isn't vnc.  Even x11 forwarded would have nothing to grab on the host.. only the client.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Well, if you assume that the question is about the terminal that's used on the SSH client side, then yes... but the question and my answer are not about that. It's about remotely capturing the contents of the server's directly-attached display (the "the console"). That the capture is done over SSH is just incidental.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the great explanation. Now that you mention it I remember from the old days that the graphics card had text display functionality on its own. I need this always on virtual machines, so no iLO or other tricks available. Maybe I can do some hacks with the virtual graphics card, I will investigate that or just switch to framebuffer.

Comment: @Daniel: Virtual machines have exactly the same trick, it's how you see the console on the host in the first place. So if the host runs X, you'd connect to the host via RDP/VNC and attach to the VM – and if the host is headless, then most VM systems still have remote console support. (For example, Qemu lets you connect to VMs via Spice and VNC; VirtualBox has VNC and RDP; Hyper-V allows the same VM management tools to connect remotely, console access included.) Only question is whether the host grants you access to that.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - **per se**